# How to compile Typescript src file into JS?

Tags: html, typescript, parceljs

I have a simple HTML file with a script src as index.ts.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="./src/index.ts"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

index.js

```
console.log("Hello!!!")
```

I wish to simply run this HTML file.

I am following a tutorial series that gives instructions on how to install Parcel, and run it with that.

However, I have been encountering issue after issue with Parcel...
I have looked through the tutorial Q&A and have tried every solution to try and get parcel working. Each solution just ends up causing another issue!

How can I get this to run? Webpack? If so, how do I configure Webpack for this? (Never used Webpack)

Comment: What's your issue with Parcel?

Comment: @Joris Literally issue after issue after issue...
I couldn't in stall it with npm first of all, so I had to install Yarn.

Then, when I try to run the parcel command within the project, it throws an error

Build failed.

@parcel/transformer-babel: Config result is not hashable because it contains non-serializable objects. Please use config.setResultHash to set the hash manually.

And if I install Parcel locally to the project, it gives the error

@parcel/core: Invalid Parcel Config

I'm following all the instructions. I just want to get it working without having to do config!

Answer (score 0):

> I wish to simply run this HTML file.

Your browser does not understand `TypeScript`. You need to transpile it. However when you *serve* this html file with parcel, it does the compilation on the fly.

What will work: So `parcel index.html` and visit `http://localhost:1234/`
What will not work: Opening the html file by itself e.g. `open index.html`

## More

See Parcel documentation : https://parceljs.org/getting_started.html

Comment: That's exactly what I am doing.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a typo in your script tag.

Try changing `<script src="./src/index.ts"></script>` to `<script src="./src/index.js"></script>`

Comment: The tutorial stated very clearly that it should be index.ts when using Parcel.